# On the notion of cuspidality

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions, adeles, supercuspidal-representations

Let $k/\mathbb{Q}$ be a number field and $\mathbb{A}$ its ring of adèles. As usual $\mathbb{A} = \mathbb{A_f} \times \mathbb{A_{\infty}}$.

The standard definition of an *automorphic representation* $(\pi,V)$ for $\textrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A})$ is its realization as (irreducible) subquotient of the space of automorphic forms $\mathcal{A}(\textrm{GL}_n(k) \backslash \textrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A})), \omega)$, where $\omega$ is some central character. This is for example in Bump's Automorphic Forms and Representations on p.300.

This implies that $(\pi,V)$ is a representation for the finite part $\textrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A_f})$  and a $(\mathfrak{g}_{\infty}, K_{\infty})$-module for $\textrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A_{\infty}})$ with the property that each two actions commute. By abuse of notation I write $\pi$ for 'all' actions.
Then there is the notion of *admissibility* of such a representation, which is fairly standard too.

However, in the Corvallis proceedings, Flath gives the notion of an (admissible) automorphic representation in a purely algebraic way, i.e. he abstracts the properties from above, but it is not clear that his definition is 'embeddable' into the space of automorphic forms, i.e. that the 2 definitions are equivalent.

What is specially not clear to my; if there is a notion of **cuspidality** in the pure algebraic description of Flath? (I am working over $\mathbb{C}$, so cuspidality = supercuspidality).

It is I think due to Jacquet that cuspidality at local non-archimedean places has equivalent meanings; by a vanishing integral and that one is *not* (properly) parabolically induced. I could therefore imagine that one can define cuspidality for $(\pi,V)$ as a representation of $\textrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A_f})$ in an analogue way. But I do not know what should be the notion of cuspidality for a $(\mathfrak{g}, K)$-module.

I am concerned with construction of $L$-functions attached to cuspidal representations. I imagine that the best way to introduce cuspidal representations is how Bump does it. However, I wondered if I can skip all the 'analytic conditions' on automorphic forms.

Comment: I think Flath speaks of general representations, not automorphic representations.

Comment: @Echo thank you for your answer! Well, yes, he abstracts the notion of an admissible automorphic representation (i.e. he leaves out the part of being realizable as space of automorphic forms) and calls such representations just admissible (not automorphic), that's true.

Hence my question; if the definition of Flat is more general, or if any admissible representation in the sense of Flath can be realized as automorphic admissible representation as introduced e.g. in Bump's book.

Comment: *Let us just stick to the $\mathrm{GL}_n$-case.

Comment: Just to be clear on one point: it is a non-trivial theorem (perhaps declared a definition in the mid-to-late 1970's) that the (irreducible) adele-group repns generated by (suitably-strong-sense) cuspforms _are_ admissible. So proving theorems about factoring, etc.,  of irreducible admissible repns of adele groups is relevant to the (irreducible) repns generated by (suitable) cuspforms. But, for general and uninteresting reasons, _most_ admissible adele-group repns are _not_ automorphic. Unsurprising, much like saying that not every real number is algebraic...

Comment: Ok, so it also does not make sense to talk about 'cuspidality' in general admissible representations in the sense of Flath, right? If one says a cuspidal representation, one necessarily means an admissible automorphic representation (realized in the space of cusp forms)

Comment: @paulgarrett do you have a reference for that 'non-trivial' theorem?

Comment: @MatyMangoo In general, an irreducible unitary representation of a linear connected reductive Lie group is admissible. See Theorem 8.1 in Knapp: Representation theory in semisimple Lie groups. This result is due to Harish-Chandra (1951) who even treated Banach space representations.

Comment: @GHfromMO thanks a lot!

Comment: Two threads: unitary repns of reductive groups over local fields, where Harish-Chandra proved admissibility for real, Bernstein for p-adic. These results were _anticipated_ (at least by optimists) because of the theorem (sketched in the Gelfand-PiatetskiShapiro book, treated more carefully by Godement in the Boulder conference) that the induced action of test functions on $L^2$ cuspforms is by compact operators, _and_ that there's an orthonormal basis $\{f_i\}$ such that there are test functions $\varphi_i$ such that $\varphi_i\cdot f_i=f_i$. This gives the admissibility.

Comment: Also, by "the theory of the constant term", a not-necessarily-$L^2$, but moderate growth (and sufficient finiteness under center of enveloping algebra, and Hecke algebras at finite places) is in fact of rapid decay, so is in $L^2$. In particular, the repns generated by such cfms are unitary.

Comment: I think I the statemente @paulgarrett meant is Theorem 5.6 and Cor.5.7 in Corvallis 2.3 (Borel-Jacquet). It appears that one does not need cuspidality for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To every local admissible representation $\pi_v$ of $\mathrm{GL}_n(k_v)$, there is a local $L$-function $L(s,\pi_v)$. For a global admissible representation $\pi=\otimes_v \pi_v$ of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A}_k)$, the corresponding global $L$-function is defined as $L(s,\pi)=\prod_v L(s,\pi_v)$. However, unless $\pi$ is automorphic, this global $L$-function will not have the usual analytic properties (cf. [converse theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_theorem)). So it is very special for a global admissible representation to be automorphic. Automorphicity of $\pi=\otimes_v \pi_v$ connects the various local factors $\pi_v$. In particular, if you change finitely many local factors $\pi_v$ in a given cuspidal automorphic representation $\pi=\otimes_v \pi_v$, the resulting global admissible representation will no longer be cuspidal automorphic (cf. [multiplicity one theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity-one_theorem)).

BTW I recommend Goldfeld-Hundley's two-volume textbook on automorphic forms (in the same series as Bump's textbook). Also, there is this [related earlier post of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349122/are-the-l-functions-of-a-normalized-newform-and-the-corresponding-cuspidal-repre/349124#349124) that you might find useful.

Comment: Thanks @GH. I see. And what is then the difference between cuspidal automorphic and just automorphic in relation with their $L$-functions? I thought one could attach $L$-fcts to cuspidal reps (as to cuspidal modular forms), as they are generic (i.e. have Whittaker models). A general automorphic form does not neet to be generic.

Comment: Oh yes, those two books are quite nice, although they only treat the case $k = \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @GH I honestly don't agree on that; an admissible representation is generic (embeddable into some induced representation of an additive char $\psi = \otimes \psi_{\nu} \colon k \backslash \mathbb{A} \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$, if and only if the local components are for $\psi_{\nu}$. There are plenty of non-generic representations, but maybe you can show me a reference for that?

Comment: @MatyMangoo The $L$-function of a (local or global) admissible representation is defined even when the representation is not generic. In the generic case, this $L$-function can also be obtained from the Whittaker function of a (local or global) newform. At any rate, the $L$-function of an automorphic representation of $\mathrm{GL}_n$ is a product of (global) cuspidal representations of $\mathrm{GL}_{n_j}$ with $n=\sum_j n_j$. It is conjectured that this decomposition is unique. See https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609460 more detail, and how this fits into the Langlands program.

Comment: @MatyMangoo Also, from a representation theoretic point of view, there is not much difference between $\mathbb{Q}$ and a number field.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "if you change finitely many local factors $\pi_{\nu}$ in a given automorphic representation $\pi=\bigotimes'_{\nu} \pi_{\nu}$ , the resulting global admissible representation will no longer be automorphic"? Due to strong multiplicity I lose 'cuspidality', but not necessarily automorphy (if that word exists)

Comment: @MatyMangoo You are right, and I have now restricted the multiplicity one property to cuspidal automorphic representations. I think this property extends to unitary isobaric automorphic representations, but I don't know a reference off-hand.